# Comebine multiple shortcuts into one representing smybol / group pinned on the taskbar

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, shortcuts

Please consider this image:

[image]

If I rightclick on the shortcut for LibreOffice Calc, all LibreOffice Calc documents I pinned to the taskbar via shortcuts are displayed in one group window (as can be seen in the screenshot).

To not congest the taskbar, I would like to achieve the same effect for the 4 "cmd.exe shortcuts" which are displayed at the bottom: One "cmd.exe" symbol representing the group of shortcuts, and (right)clicking on it offers me these 4 possibilites.

How can this be achieved?

More information: All these 4 "cmd.exe shortcuts" are shortcuts to .bat files and their target entry is *C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C "pathToRespectiveScript.bat"*

Comment: Have a look at the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have this option selected?

**Right click** on the task bar and select **properties**.

Make sure under taskbar buttons you have **Always combine, Hide Labels.**

[image]

**UPDATE**

Calling up Each batch on its own. Since they are named different they are not grouped together.

Its opening each batch file as its own since the Batch files are not the same.

If You need to run all the batch files at the same time you could do this.

Create 1 batch file to start your batch files.

example below.

so **new.bat** opens up **1.bat,2.bat,3.bat**

[image]

*Note: The Pause is in there for visual purposes.*

**Last Update**

**Batch Menu**

Example Code.

```
ECHO OFF
CLS
:MENU
ECHO.
ECHO ...............................................
ECHO PRESS 1, 2 OR 3 to select your task, or 4 to EXIT.
ECHO ...............................................
ECHO.
ECHO 1 - Open Batch 1
ECHO 2 - Open Batch 2
ECHO 3 - Open Batch 3
ECHO 4 - EXIT
ECHO.
SET /P M=Type 1, 2, 3, or 4 then press ENTER:
IF %M%==1 GOTO BAT1
IF %M%==2 GOTO BAT2
IF %M%==3 GOTO BAT3
IF %M%==4 GOTO EOF
:BAT1
cd C:\Users\MBurris\Desktop\1.bat
start 1.bat
GOTO MENU
:BAT2
cd C:\Users\MBurris\Desktop\2.bat
start 2.bat
GOTO MENU
:BAT3
cd C:\Users\MBurris\Desktop\3.bat
start 3.bat
GOTO MENU
```

[image]

This will allow you to open up the batch files individually through the menu.

You can add more options by add values such as below.

**example.**

```
ECHO 5 - Open 4.bat
```

**then add in the IF area**

```
IF %M%==5 GOTO BAT4
```

**Then add**

```
GOTO MENU
:4BAT
[ADD YOUR PATH HERE]
start 4.bat
```

Let me know if this helps you out.

Comment: @David'mArm'Ansermot Your welcome

Comment: @NetworkKingPin This option is already selected. Unfortunately, it does not help. I added a little bit more info such that what my setup is can be simulated.

Comment: @efie I will look into this let me test some things.

Comment: @efie okay I see what you are doing now. They are opening up as individual Command Prompt windows which is why it is not consolidating them.

Comment: Yes, exactly! It would be great to find a way to combine them, as I don't want to clutter my taskbar with my scripts.

Comment: @efie let me know if this is what you are looking for or post an example of what you want.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin Thanks a lot for your help, but I need to run them individually and not at the same time.

Comment: One moment I will add one last edit in.

Comment: Thanks, this looks good! I'll wait a bit, maybe someone comes up with a soluation which requires less code.